# preg_replace and use value in variable name

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$clasa = 'HHH';
$length = '100';
$width = 200;
$depth = 300; 


$string1 = '{{clasa}}{{length}}{{width}}';
$string2 = '{{clasa}}{{length}}{{depth}}';
$string3 = '{{clasa}}_word{{length}},anything{{depth}}';

$new1 = preg_replace('/{{([a-zA-Z\_\-]*?)}}/', ${'"$1"'}, $string1);

echo $new1;   

?>
```

My new string should be HHH100200

I have added $depth variable so that you'll see that my string will not always use the same variables.
I am pretty close on doing this but cannot create the variable name;

Also - I am not familiar with regex - I only want to allow a-zA-Z0-9 inside the brackets.

Comment: If you want to use variable variables you want to look at `preg_replace_callback()`, and you don't want to forget that PHP has function scope for the variables.

Comment: Then I will have to declare global for what i do not yet know I will use.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but you can do it with variable variables.

Comment: Unexpected bracket where I am not using any  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9364d01e5310cfe2f2d87d89d6d551db6ae8b337

Comment: *"I only want to allow a-zA-Z0-9 inside the brackets"*: in this case why did you add `_` and `-`?

Comment: More something like this: https://3v4l.org/iqalh Just without checking if the variable exists and `length` corrected

Comment: I took the regex  code as is, without understanding the rules. Is /{{([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)}}/  the correct rule?

Comment: @Rizier123 - that is exactly what I needed.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Using regex here is not the way to go, use an array with `strtr` or `str_replace`:

```
$trans = ['{{clasa}}'  => 'HHH',
          '{{length}}' => '100',
          '{{width}}'  => '200',
          '{{depth}}'  => '300'];

$str1 = strtr($str1, $trans);
```

Comment: That was the way I would've don it if I knew that these variables are all I will use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Rizier123

```
<?php

$clasa = 'HHH';
$length = '100';
$width = 200;
$depth = 300; 


$string1 = '{{clasa}}{{length}}{{width}}';
$string2 = '{{clasa}}{{lenght}}{{depth}}';
$string3 = '{{clasa}}_word{{lenght}},anything{{depth}}';

//$new1 = preg_replace('/{{([a-zA-Z\_\-]*?)}}/', ${'"$1"'}, $string1);
$new1 = preg_replace_callback("/{{([a-zA-Z\_\-]*?)}}/", function($m){
    global ${$m["1"]};
    return ${$m["1"]};
}, $string1);

echo $new1;
```